# How to get siphon to recognize SSL cert bundle

Tags: ssl, python-siphon

I’m trying to use siphon from behind a pretty aggressive firewall, but I can’t figure out how to get siphon to recognize my SSL certs.  Constructing a TDSCatalog fails with

Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])

I verified the certs themselves are good, just not sure how to pass them to siphon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siphon uses the `requests` module for HTTP access, and from the [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) it looks like you can pass certs to `session()` to use for HTTPS verification using the `verify` argument.

To hook into this for creating HTTP sessions in Siphon, you can access `siphon.http_util.session_manager` to set some default options, like is done in [this example](https://unidata.github.io/siphon/latest/examples/Basic_Usage.html#sphx-glr-examples-basic-usage-py) for HTTP authorization. So I think this would work:

```
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
from siphon.http_util import session_manager
session_manager.set_session_options(verify='path/to/my/cert')
cat = TDSCatalog('https://myserver.net/thredds/catalog.xml')
```

I'm not sure what problem you're having exactly, but you may need to use the `cert` attribute instead of `verify`.